# Define CSS style in Django model field

Tags: python, css, django, django-models

Suppose I have a following code:

File models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyClass(models.Model):
   username = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
   my_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="sample_field")

File views.py

from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp.models import MyClass

@login_required
def index(request):

    username = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)

    MyClassFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, MyClass, can_delete=False, extra=5)

    formset = MyClassFormSet(instance=username) 
    ...
```

What is the easiest way to add CSS class to the field my_field here?
(I saw some answers on SO for forms, but not for models).

Comment: Why would a model have way to add css attribute, model should not know about the view, even if it is possible please don't do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a form from the model and define UI attributes there, that is the correct place to do it e.g.

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyClass
        fields = ('my_field')
        widgets = {
            'my_field': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'mycssclass'}),
        }
```

That should set correct class for your field, then in HTML file set the needed css attributes e.g.

```
.mycssclass {
    color: red;
}
```

If you are using `inlineformset_factory` you can still pass a `widgets` dict to it, where `widgets` is a dictionary of model field names mapped to a widget, or you can pass a custom `form` to it, so you can do something like this

```
MyClassFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, MyClass, form=MyForm, can_delete=False, extra=5)
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the form is the way to go. I edited my question, since in reality my case is more involved as it uses inlineformset_factory. Can I still use ModelForm with it? (You can find my updated code in the question).

Comment: @GregoryR see my edit, you can pass widgets or form to inlineformset_factory