# Django crispy forms: add text next to a checkbox?

Tags: python, django, checkbox, django-crispy-forms

It seems to be simple but I can't figure out how to add some text next to my checkbox. I don't want to override the template (I think I don't need to).
For now, I have a checkbox that works, but how to put some text like "I Agree TOS" at the right of the checkbox?

Here is what I have:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3n5rivhzfvo2ms/Screenshot%202015-06-30%2012.10.46.png?dl=0

```
class TenantSignupForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
        validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]{8,}', code=None),
                    MaxLengthValidator(32)])
    password_confirmation = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    agree_tos = forms.BooleanField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TenantSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = unvariable_helper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'm-t'
        self.helper.form_action = 'signup'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('email', placeholder="Email"),
            Field('password', placeholder="Password"),
            Field('password_confirmation', placeholder="Confirm your password"),
            Field('agree_tos', wrapper_class='i-checks'),
            FormActions(
                Submit('signup',
                       'Register',
                       css_class='btn btn-primary block full-width m-b'
                      )
                )
        )
```

Comment: if nothing helps - simply override it's template :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377786/django-crispy-forms-and-bootstrap-awesome-checkbox/30379092#30379092

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `crispy-forms`, but may be adding `help_text` could help

```
agree_tos = forms.BooleanField(help_text="I Agree TOS")
```

UPDATE: Another guess

```
agree_tos = forms.BooleanField(label="I Agree TOS")
```

Comment: That's a good try but unfortunately, this adds the text outside of the `div` as you can see [there](https://www.dropbox.com/s/12nvrxpezpwxmyo/Screenshot%202015-06-30%2012.22.09.png?dl=0)

Comment: Arf. It works if I set `form.helper.form_show_labels = True`, but I wanted to avoid label for textinput fields. [Take a look here please](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cf3a9k0k8x6jas2/Screenshot%202015-06-30%2012.53.44.png?dl=0)

Comment: I found a way to do it thanks to your ideas. If I set `label=""` for all fields except `agree_tos`it works as expected. However, it's not very DRY to repeat `label=""` for a majority of fields. I'd like to do it in the other way: set `form.helper.form_show_labels = False` then override this only for my checkbox. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying each **Form widget** separately in the template, then you could add the required text next to the following widget.

```
{{ form.agree_tos }}
```

Comment: No I'm using `{% crispy form %}` to display the whole form (and I want to keep doing this).

Answer (score 0):

As for me the best way is using a specific template for this field:

`Field('agree_tos', template="{0}/tos.html".format(TEMPLATE_PACK))`

Depending on Template_pack used, you have to look at the default template (field.html) in the corresponding directory (say, uni_form or bootstrap) and make your own template quickly and easily.